# How to remove F-curve cycle

Tags: curve-modifier

Today is a nice day. I turn on my computer to start to make a blender animation. I press Ctrl shift E
to make a loop animation. but I want to remove the loop now. How to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what Ctrl Shift E is for, but maybe try Shift E > Clear Cyclic? Also you can remove the Cycles modifier in the N panel of the Graph Editor

Comment: That combination seems to only be used in the Grease Pencil and text input windows by default.